# Bash - Remove upper and lower lines from file using variables

Tags: bash, sed, vi

I have to build a bash script that removes upper and lower lines from a file.

The script ask the person for a word, searches the word in the file and removes 4 upper lines, 9 lower lines and the line that contains the word.

Bellow are the commands that works:

```
vi -e -c 'g/word/.-4,-d' -c 'wq' fileName

sed -i '/word/,+9d' fileName
```

The problem is that I want to ask the user for a word that I will use as a variable to do all that.

The bellow code doesn't work!

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Insert the word:" word

vi -e -c 'g/$word/.-4,-d' -c 'wq' fileName

sed -i '/$word/,+9d' fileName
```

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash answer you question?

Answer (score 1):

something like this will work, assumes the search word appears only once in the file

```
$ awk -v b=4 -v a=9 -v word="$word" 'NR==FNR{if($0~word) n=NR; next} 
                                     FNR<n-b || FNR>n+a' file{,}
```

double scans the file, first to find the line number of the match, second round prints out the lines based on before/after context set.

Also doesn't handle if the search word not found.  If you want to print everything add `!n ||` to the last condition

Answer (score 0):

You can do it one shot with `vi` or `ed`, no need to use `sed`. Variables inside single quotes won't be interpolated, you need double quotes for that. See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/4082052) for details.

```sh
vi -e -c 'g/'"$word"'/.-4,+9d' -c 'wq' fileName

printf '/%s/\n-4,+9d\nwq\n' "$word" | ed -s fileName > /dev/null
```

I don't know `ed` enough to prevent the line matching the given word from being printed, hence the use of `/dev/null`